# How to transform values according to matching values in another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I have 2 data frames with a column that has the same type of values, as shown here:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c("John", "James", "James", "John")
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)
c <- c("John", "James")
d <- c("A", "B")
df2 <- data.frame(c, d)
```

In `df1`, I want to turn the `John` and `James` into `A` and `B`, using `df2`, which shows that `John` goes with `A` and `James` goes with `B`. Thus, df1 should look like this:

```
a   b
1   A           
2   B           
3   B           
4   A
```

I tried using the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
df1$b[df1$b == df2$c] <- df2$d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution with `left_join()` from dplyr. It joins the two data.frames by matching up the values in the `df1$b` and `df2$c`:

```
library(dplyr)

a <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
b <- c("John", "James", "James", "John")
df1 <- data.frame(a, b)
c <- c("John", "James")
d <- c("A", "B")
df2 <- data.frame(c, d)

left_join(df1, df2, by = c("b" = "c"))
```

Output:

```
  a     b d
1 1  John A
2 2 James B
3 3 James B
4 4  John A
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sqldf`:
We can perform `join` on column `b` from `df1` and `c` from `df2` as follow:

```
sqldf("select d from df1 join df2 on df1.b=df2.c")
```

Output:

```
  d
1 A
2 B
3 B
4 A
```

**OR**

In order to use `merge` please make sure that your join column should have same name:

```
merge(df1,df2,by = "b")
      b a d
1 James 2 B
2 James 3 B
3  John 1 A
4  John 4 A
```